# Invoking Standalone Java Program from a Multi-threaded Client

Tags: java, parallel-processing

I have a 3rd party standalone Java program. I want to run it from a Java client that will invoke this program via multiple threads to achieve parallel execution. Challenge is, this 3rd party program reads configuration parameters from environment variables. I don't want parallel threads to override each other's configuration. Also, since my Client and this 3rd party program are both written in Java, if I can avoid creating multiple JVM processes then it will be great value add.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`ProcessBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html), and populate the map returned by the [`environment()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#environment%28%29) method.

```
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("java -cp . Foo");
Map<String, String> environment = builder.environment();
environment.put("Foo", "Bar");
environment.put("X", "Y");
Process process = builder.start();
```

As each process has its own environment, this should be safe.

Alternatively, you can use [`Runtime.exec`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D%29).